# ¿Porqué no se crean todas los índices de mis tablas?

Tags: sql, powershell, indices

Buen día compañeros. Estoy teniendo un problema al crear los índices de las tablas de una bases de datos, lo estoy realizando mediante `powershell`, la verdad soy muy principiante en `PS` pero investigué en foros en español, inglés, la documentación y no encontré respuesta. El bloque donde se crea el fichero `sql` está dentro de una función y antes de correr la función como creo una query para obtener todos las tablas(Funciona correctamente) y mando los datos como parámetros cuando ejecuto la función

Este es el pedazo de código:

```
foreach ($table in $TBLs | where {!($_.IsSystemObject)}  ){
            foreach ($Index in $table.Indexes | where {!($_.IsSystemObject)}){
            $ScriptIndex = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMOserver)
            $ScriptIndex.Options = $CreationScriptOptions
            $ScriptIndex.Options.DriAll = $True
            $ScriptIndex.Options.Indexes = $True
            $Bien = $Index.GetType().Name
            $TypeFolder= "$($Bien)_ParaVerificarPKs"
            Write-Host "$TypeFolder"
            $ScriptIndex.Options.FileName = "$finalPath\$TypeFolder.SQL"        
            $ScriptIndex.Script($Index) 
            }
        }
```

Donde la `$TBLs` recibe las los registros. Tengo entendido que `$ScriptIndex.Options.Indexes = $True` crea los índices de las tablas, y si, crea la gran mayoría de los índices, pero quedan algúnos que no entiendo porque no los crea.

Comparé algunas tablas para ver si había alguna razón en especial y no parece a simple vista. Una de las tablas que no crea índices tiene también una `FK`, pero otras de las tablas también las tienen y crea los índices. Otra sería una tabla con índices no clúster, pero también hay más tablas con este tipo de índices y si crea los índices.

Agradezco su ayuda de antemano, saludos.